# OpenOffice Calc: How to convert cell A's multi-string value to a single-string value in cell B

Tags: openoffice-calc

stackoverflow

I've got this CSV file containing product information which I need to edit:

1) Each row corresponds to one specific product

2) Column A lists categories which this product belongs to, presented in the following way (vertical bar is used as a delimiter for a string):

```
Mount type|Standalone
Purpose|Functional|Watches
Color|White
Style|Classical
```

If particular product has more than one color, cells in column A allow listing numerous strings with the same attribute and different values, i.e.:

```
Mount type|Standalone
Purpose|Functional|Watches
Color|White
Color|Blue
Color|Gray
Style|Classical
```

3) Column B contains product attributes, which looks like this:

```
Attribute|Model|1-0001
Attribute|Material:|Resin
Attribute|Type:|Watch
Attribute|Mount type:|Standalone
Attribute|Color:|White
Attribute|Style:|Classical
Attribute|Height:|10
Attribute|Width:|5
Attribute|Weight:|4
```

Cells in column B, however, do not allow to have multiple strings with the same attribute and different values. So one **could not** have

```
Attribute|Model|1-0001
Attribute|Material:|Resin
Attribute|Type:|Watch
Attribute|Mount type:|Standalone
Attribute|Color:|White
Attribute|Color:|Blue
Attribute|Color:|Gray
Attribute|Style:|Classical
Attribute|Height:|10
Attribute|Width:|5
Attribute|Weight:|4
```

because following the unique attribute rule, cell's 'color' value will be collapsed to topmost (first) string of said attribute, - 'Attribute|Color:|White' in this example, - deleting other strings with attribute 'color', resulting in loss of data.

And this is exactly what happened, as I've had mistakenly listed Color attribute for each product using different lines, instead of (as I now know) separating them with a comma and a blank space. Thus I now have a file with close to 1900 rows of product characteristics with their color attributes mangled: all the single-colored ones didn't suffer any damage, but all the multi-colored ones have only one color listed, with others destroyed.

Could you please help me edit data in this file in such a way so that Color attribute in column B becomes a single line attribute with values separated by ', ', based on column A's value (also leaving all other values in this cell unchanged):

Current text in A and B:

```
  Column A                                               Column B
Mount type|Standalone                                Attribute|Model|1-0001
Purpose|Functional|Watches                           Attribute|Material:|Resin
Color|White                                          Attribute|Type:|Watch
Color|Blue                                           Attribute|Mount type:|Standalone
Color|Gray                                           Attribute|Color:|White
Style|Classical                                      Attribute|Style:|Classical
                                                     Attribute|Height:|10
                                                     Attribute|Width:|5
                                                     Attribute|Weight:|4
```

Becomes:

```
  Column A                                               Column B
Mount type|Standalone                                Attribute|Model|1-0001
Purpose|Functional|Watches                           Attribute|Material:|Resin
Color|White                                          Attribute|Type:|Watch
Color|Blue                                           Attribute|Mount type:|Standalone
Color|Gray                                           Attribute|Color:|White, Blue, Gray
Style|Classical                                      Attribute|Style:|Classical
                                                     Attribute|Height:|10
                                                     Attribute|Width:|5
                                                     Attribute|Weight:|4
```

Tackling this is surely beyond my capability, so I really hope you could help out. 
Thank you for your time and effort.